# Typescript/ES6: import src files with absolute path

Tags: typescript

in one of my files I import another commonjs module with

```
import * as at from '../../../at-angular'
```

I would much rather do

```
import * as at from 'fv/at-angular'
```

with `fv` being my `src` directory. So my app folder structure looks like this:

```
- src
  - at-angular.ts
  - core
    - services
  ....
```

Can I somehow enable typescript to have `fv` point to `src`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reference typescript files without absolute paths?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822836/how-can-i-reference-typescript-files-without-absolute-paths)

Comment: Its not a duplicate. i am pretty sure what he means is he wants to bundle the files with absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript 1.8 (not released yet) will have *path mapping* feature:

> **Path mappings**
>
> Sometimes modules are not directly located under baseUrl. It is
>   possible to control how locations are computed in such cases using
>   path mappings. Path mappings are specified using the following JSON
>   structure:
>
> ```
> {
>     "paths": {
>         "pattern-1": "substitution" | ["list of substitutions"],
>         "pattern-2": "substitution" | ["list of substitutions"],
>         ...
>         "pattern-N": "substitution" | ["list of substitutions"]
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Patterns and substitutions are strings that can have zero or one
>   asteriks ('*').  Interpretation of both patterns and substitutions
>   will be described in Resolution process section.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039

It may be what you are looking for.

Comment: And yet your answer is not working since that is only works for the compiler to understand where the modules are located. But after transpiling the paths are not updated and it will cause errors in any app node or webpack..

Comment: @azarus: maybe I should delete this post I don't follow TypeScript closely now. I don't know what the proper way to solve it atm.

Comment: Sadly no proper way but to target ESnext in tsc then to use babel to transform the modules.

Comment: I've posted an answer that transforms the module names to their proper location based on the tsconfig.json path mappings.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get absolute path import working on my webpack2 setup.  Here is that I did You have to set up the tsconfig.json to support that as well.  Here is an example: https://medium.com/@timwong/typescript-with-webpack2-how-to-do-import-with-absolute-path-f33b1826d330

Here is the example in my post.

Webpack2 Resolve

```
/** 
* Assuming the following project structure
*   /src
*     /app
*       /services
*       /models
*     /node_modules
*     .webpack.config.js
*     tsconfig.json
*/
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  module: { ... },
  devtool: '...',
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve('./node_modules'),
      path.resolve('./app')
    ]
  }
```

By defining the resolve.modules, we instruct Webpack to search (a.k.a resolve) the components using these paths as root folder.
TypeScript Configuration

Ok, now that Webpack is good to go; what about TypeScript. If you are using an editor such as Atom or VSCode, you will likely be seeing an highlighted error saying that TypeScript can’t find the modules.
It is because TypeScript is not aware of this root module setting. We have to provide this information in the tsconfig.json as well.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "app/*"
      ]
    }
}
```

By defining the paths object and the baseUrl, we instruct TypeScript compiler to look into the app folder when resolving import statements.
Hope this simple example helps to unblock anyone who faces this configuration problem when first getting started with TypeScript and Webpack2.

Comment: Can you include the example within your answer. Links can die over time and mean that other Stack user cannot benefit form this Q&A

Comment: Sure @Todd, added my example.

Comment: Thanks for including that

Answer (score 0):

I've created a gist for the source code to use absolute path names or any other paths deifned in the tsconfig.json
It works well with Browserify+Watchify+Tsify also works with Gulp-typescript.

https://gist.github.com/azarus/f369ee2ab0283ba0793b0ccf0e9ec590

It transforms path names & baseUrl defined in the tsconfig.json to their relative path names.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup and it works. Just build and when you want to run code in your dist directory using node you have to pass NODE_PATH=dist.

add this script to your package.json scripts and run it to test that everything works ok.

```
"build-test": "NODE_PATH=dist node --inspect dist"
```